# Hibernate: ThreadLocalSessionContext: Already session bound on call to bind()

Tags: hibernate, struts, hibernate-session

When I try to use the ThreadLocalSessionContext in the following way:

```
Session hsession = HibernateUtils.getSession();
ThreadLocalSessionContext.bind(hsession);
// do stuff
hsession.close();
```

I do this for every single Struts Action. Is there something I am doing wrong, causing me to get the following error?

```
[ThreadLocalSessionContext] Already session bound on call to bind(); make sure you clean up your sessions!
```

I checked all my files that had ThreadLocalSessionContext.bind in them and made sure these sessions are explicitly closed.  Is there a way to monitor when sessions are binded onto session factories?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, although the [documentation](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/context/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html) indicates that "If close() is called on a session managed by this class, it will be automatically unbound." It is actually NOT automatic!

You have to explicitly call `ThreadLocalSessionContext.unbind(sessionFactory)` to unbind the session. Otherwise, even if a session gets closed, it still stays binded to the SessionFactory.